# c# - Linq Query to retrieve all objects with a max value

Tags: c#, linq

Currently I have a `List` of objects in which I need to find **all** occurrences that have the maximum value.

Currently my solution to this has been:

```
Foo maxFoo = list.OrderByDescending(foo => foo.A).First();
List<Foo> maxFoos = new List<Foo>();

foreach(Foo foo in list) {
    if (foo.A.Equals(maxFoo.A)) {
        maxFoos.Add(foo);
    }
}
```

However I want to know if there is a way to do this in a single `Linq` expression.

All the resources I have read only refer to getting the max value for one object.

**Note:** For the time being, I want to know a solution which doesn't rely on [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by the property, then order the groups by key, and take the content of the first one, like this:

```
var res = list
    .GroupBy(item => item.A)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .First()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could group by `A`, order the group, and get the elements in the first group, which corresponds to the elements with the max value of A:

```
list
  .GroupBy(x => x.A)
  .OrderByDescending(grp=> grp.Key)
  .First()
  .Select(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var maxFoos =
    list
        .OrderByDescending(foo => foo.A)
        .GroupBy(foo => foo.A)
        .Take(1)
        .SelectMany(foo => foo)
        .ToList();
```